# Cakephp none add action forms

Tags: php, cakephp

I have an index action in one of my controllers.

In this index action i wish to create a "search" form that calls another action within my controller with a post request.

All the documentation i could find on form creation in cakephp is about creating new elements (i.e insert data into a database ) and not actually sending data to another action / function.

here is an example:

```
    <?php echo $this->Form->create('Product'); ?>
<fieldset>
    <legend><?php echo __('Søg Produkt'); ?></legend>
    <?php
    echo $this->Form->input('Search field');
    ?>
</fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Søg')); ?>
```

How would i send the value of my `search field` to another action? (so it redirects to that action and sends data to it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to [read the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#options-for-create)?

```
$this->Form->create('Product', array('url' => array('action' => 'search');
```

Comment: Thanks mate i must have missed it in the documentation